# How did Amy and Rory see themselves from 10 years in the future

Tags: doctor-who

In season 5 episode 9, Amy and Rory see themselves from 10 years in the future waving at them. However,

> Amy and Rory get zapped in the past by the angels.

So how do they visit the town to re-live  the good old times.

Comment: Timey-wimey wibbly-wobbly

Comment: "Time can be rewritten."

Comment: *"We think it's been ten years. Not for you, or Earth. But for us. Ten years older, ten years of you. On and off."* - Amelia Pond, ("The Power of Three", S07E04, 04:24-04:33)  So, by the episode you reference in spoilers, they have had enough time to go and wave to their 10-years-younger selves.